# Mail.app smart mailbox "match any" problem

Tags: mail.app

Anyone know why this doesn't work?
If I remove either of the rules I get emails but never if I have both.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently it's a known bug.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3119920?start=0&tstart=0)

> Helpful AnswerRe: Mail.app : smart Mailbox misbehaves with condition "any"
>   15-Jun-2011 08:47 (in response to Claude Cauwe)
>
> That's a known bug.  I've reported it, and was told that it was already something Apple is aware of.  Evidently hasn't been fixed yet, though.

Edit: I've just checked, and the bug appears to be fixed in Mail.app from Lion. At least it works as expected ([mich732](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10932)).

Answer (score -2):

Your rules require the email to contain BOTH yandexbot AND slurp in order to qualify.

It is frustrating because there is no option for either yandexbot OR slurp, which is what I think you want.

Have you tried to put both words in one rule, separated by a comma?  That just occurred to me as a possible solution.